# Reactjs Griddle Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am started working on Reactjs Griddle Grid while implement, i am getting an error while implement the code.I am thinking this is the basic error but i am able to resolve.The error is"ReferenceError: fakeData is not defined".please help me to reslove.

My code is:

```
export default class Products extends Component {
debugger;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {  };
    this.state.filterText = "";
    this.fakeData =  [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Mayer Leonard",
    "city": "Kapowsin",
    "state": "Hawaii",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "company": "Ovolo",
    "favoriteNumber": 7
  },

];
  }

  render() {

    return (
<Griddle results={fakeData} tableClassName="table" showFilter={true}
 showSettings={true} columns={["name", "city", "state", "country"]}/>
    );

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this.fakeData that should work

```
<Griddle results={this.fakeData} tableClassName="table" showFilter={true}
 showSettings={true} columns={["name", "city", "state", "country"]}/>
```

Comment: I need to place a button top of the Griddle is it possible?

Comment: for what use you need button on top? griddle documentation comes with  ways you can customize  griddle can you be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I see you took the sample code from [`Griddle Documentation`](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/quickstart.html) and their example without Class. so they called the variable.

In your example, its a Class Member data.

```
export default class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
        this.state.filterText = "";
        this.fakeData = [{
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Mayer Leonard",
                "city": "Kapowsin",
                "state": "Hawaii",
                "country": "United Kingdom",
                "company": "Ovolo",
                "favoriteNumber": 7
            },

        ];
    }

    render() {

        return ( <Griddle results = {this.fakeData}
            tableClassName = "table"
            showFilter = {
                true
            }
            showSettings = {
                true
            }
            columns = {
                ["name", "city", "state", "country"]
            }
            />
        );

    }

}
```

I suggest you to understand [`ES6 Basics`](http://es6-features.org/) and `Griddle examples`.